# Hibernate: how to have two collection fields pointing to same objects

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm trying to map two ordered collection one-to-many fields to the same values. The fields have different filtering requirements. So one field will have items that are filtered out of the other.

Here's the relevant part of the entity.

```
public class OptionValueSet extends ConfigurationDomainObject {
    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = OPTION_VALUE_SET_ID_COLUMN, nullable = false)
    @IndexColumn(name = "option_index", nullable = false)
    @Where(clause = OBSOLETE_FILTER)
    private final List<OptionValue> allOptions = new java.util.ArrayList<OptionValue>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = OPTION_VALUE_SET_ID_COLUMN, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @IndexColumn(name = "option_index", nullable = false)
    @Where(clause = OBSOLETE_FILTER + " AND disabled = '0'")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    @Immutable
    private final List<OptionValue> options = new java.util.ArrayList<OptionValue>();

    ...
}
```

And the exception

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.casenet.domain.configuration.screen.OptionValue column: option_value_set_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1320)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    ... 137 more
```

For the curious, I'm in the process of disentangling two use cases that are using the same hibernate field. Currently, the filter is turned on in one to hide disabled OptionValues, left on in the other to edit them. However, the @Filter annotation is interfering with caching. I must fix this without changing the underlying DB schema. We're too late in the release cycle to be doing anything more radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those collections are eagerly fetched anyway, why don't you simply add a getOptions() method that returns a filtered view (or copy) of `allOptions`?

```
public List<OptionValue> getOptions() {
    List<OptionValue> result = new ArrayList<OptionValue>(allOptions.size());
    for (OptionValue o : allOptions) {
        if (!o.isDisabled()) {
            result.add(o);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble with a similar question in which I am trying to create three separate lists, each with different filters of the same object type in a spring hibernate application.  Do you have a little time to help me figure out the solution?  The problem is at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292152/parameterizing-object-properties

Answer (score 0):

In the idea of hibernate you have mapped the same field two times (in this case a child list; you'll get the same error message if you map a simple property two times). Hibernate can't handle it because after update or insert the state might be invalid (what should hibernate do if the object, which is mapped two times, got different values for update in the Java code?).

You can map a field two times if one of the two fields only is for reading. In case of simple properties the error message already tells you how to do (`insert="false" update="false"`). In your case of a child list probably you also have to set `cascade` to `none` for the read-only property.